# GPSTrack from exif

Tags: gps, exif

How would I convert the [rational64u](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/GPS.html) `GPSTrack` --from an exif-- into a direction?

with:

```py
import piexif
exif_dict = piexif.load('./img/IMG_1146.jpg')  
h = exif_dict['GPS'][piexif.GPSIFD.GPSTrack]  
h
```

we get: `(116001, 424)`
with [metapix](http://metapicz.com/#landing) the result is: `GPSTrack 273.5872642`. An example image [here](https://github.com/AdrianKriger/aerialPhotogrammetry101/blob/main/SenseMor_127/img/IMG_1146.JPG).

What must I do to `(116001, 424)` to get a bearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `rational64u` (as used in latitudes and longitudes, and in many places in EXIF) so a float is represented by two integers, a numerator and a denominator.

To get the float, you just divide the two:

```
degree = numerator / denominator
```

so

```
degree = numerator / denominator = 116001 / 424 = 273.587264150943
```

Usual warning: carious computer languages will do an integer division if the two operand are integer, so you may need to cast them to floats before doing the division.

Comment: lol ~ I've been trying permutations of multiply by and divide by 60 and 3600. I feel a fool. Thank you.